# Get Local Time Month Name in report builder (SSRS)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I wrote this `SSRS` expression to get the month name, it gives the month name in English, but I want to get the Local Time or specific culture month name (eg. Serbian).

How to solve in `SSRS`?

```
MonthName(Month(Today()))
```

Comment: You have both the [C#] tag and the [reporting-services] (SSRS) tag. Do you need a solution in SSRS or can it be solved in C#? If you don't want a C# solution, you should probably remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

My initial though was that you can do it by using [`SET LANGUAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) before getting the month name.

However, turns out that Sql Server does not support Serbian language (it's not in `sys.syslanguages` at least in Sql Server 2012), so your best option is to create a table or cte with the localized month names and numbers and use it instead of the `MonthName` function.
**Edit**
Actually, a table will serve you better as it will only be needed to created once:

```
CREATE TABLE SerbianMonths (
    SerbianMonths_Id int,
    SerbianMonths_Name nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO SerbianMonths VALUES 
(1, N'јануар'),
(2, N'фебруар'),
(3, N'март'),
(4, N'април'),
(5, N'мај'),
(6, N'јун'),
(7, N'јул'),
(8, N'август'),
(9, N'септембар'),
(10, N'октобар'),
(11, N'новембар'),
(12, N'децембар')
```

(Sorry if I've got the spelling wrong, I've copied from [this website](http://wikitravel.org/en/Serbian_phrasebook))

You can then create your own user-defined function to get the month name by it's number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSerbianMonthName
(
    @MonthNumber int
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MonthName nvarchar(10)
    SELECT @MonthName = SerbianMonths_Name
    FROM SerbianMonths
    WHERE SerbianMonths_Id = @MonthNumber
    RETURN @MonthName
END
```

and use it like this: `SELECT dbo.GetSerbianMonthName(2)`

If you want to use more unsupported languages, you can add a language table and a language_id column to your months table:

```
CREATE TABLE Languages 
(
    Language_Id int,
    Language_Name nvarchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE MonthNames 
(
    MonthNames_MonthNumber int, -- values from 1 to 12
    MonthNames_LanguageId int, -- FK to languages table
    MonthNames_Name nvarchar(100) -- the local month name
)
```

set a composite primary key on both MonthNumber and LanguageId, 
and add the language id to your select from this table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMonthName
(
    @Language_Id int,
    @MonthNumber int
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MonthName nvarchar(100)
    SELECT @MonthName = MonthNames_Name 
    FROM MonthNames 
    WHERE MonthNames_MonthNumber = @MonthNumber
    AND MonthNames_LanguageId  = @Language_Id
    RETURN @MonthName
END
```

Comment: How can create CTE with the localized month names? Some solutions?